# Report designing issue using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am designing an invoice using *iReport* but i am having a problem with formatting.

I have to print invoice on letter head, where there are fixed positions to print the fields for example the total Amount has to get printed inside the box fixed at some location.

This is format of letter head:

[image]

At the bottom there is a field where total amount has to get printed, but i am not able to do so.

My output using *iReport*:

Screen Shot of iReport

[image]

[image]

This is my jrxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="LetterHeadInvoice" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="COMPANY_ADDRESS" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="COMPANY_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="INVOICENO" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT DISTINCT c.docketno,c.bookingdate,c.rname,c.rcity,c.rcountry
       ,c.noofitems,c.actualweight,c.volweight,p.docketcharges,p.weight as weightused,
       p.total,i.type,c.sname,c.scity,c.scountry,c.bookingdate,s.fovtype ,s.fovamount,s.oditype ,s.odiamount,s.nformtype ,s.nformamount,o.fsetype,o.fseamount
 FROM  typedetails i,paymentdetails p,clientdetails c,subdetails s,otherdetails o
 WHERE i.id=c.typeid
 AND   c.docketno=p.docketno
And c.docketno= s.docketno
And c.docketno= o.docketno
  AND   c.docketno IN (SELECT docketnumber FROM invoice  WHERE InvoiceId=$P{INVOICENO})]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="docketno" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="bookingdate" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="rname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="rcity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="rcountry" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="noofitems" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="actualweight" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="volweight" class="java.lang.Short"/>
    <field name="docketcharges" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="weightused" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="total" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="type" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="sname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="scity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="scountry" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fovtype" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fovamount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="oditype" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="odiamount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nformtype" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nformamount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fsetype" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fseamount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="TOTAL" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{total}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOTAL2" class="java.lang.Double" incrementType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL}+$F{fseamount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="Tax" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL2}/100.00*12.36]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="802"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Documents and Settings\\Hemant\\Desktop\\RNZImage.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="205" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="40" y="61" width="40" height="23"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Bright" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Bill To]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="84" width="266" height="107"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sname}+"\n"+$F{scity}+","+$F{scountry}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="324" y="95" width="91" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{INVOICENO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="429" y="96" width="104" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM-yy">
                <reportElement x="312" y="145" width="83" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="112" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="28" y="31" width="52" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bookingdate}.toString().substring(0,$F{bookingdate}.toString().indexOf(" "))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="82" y="31" width="54" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{docketno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="164" y="31" width="77" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rcity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="261" y="31" width="35" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rcity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="306" y="31" width="33" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{noofitems}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="345" y="31" width="33" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{weightused}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="395" y="31" width="73" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{type}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="480" y="31" width="48" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{docketcharges}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="346" y="90" width="123" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{oditype}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="480" y="90" width="55" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="346" y="56" width="123" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fovtype}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="480" y="73" width="55" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nformamount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="346" y="73" width="123" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nformtype}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="480" y="56" width="55" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fovamount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="280" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="478" y="12" width="59" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="none"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="334" y="32" width="128" height="17">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fsetype}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="478" y="32" width="59" height="17">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{odiamount} != null && $F{odiamount}.trim().length()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fseamount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="49" width="128" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="12" width="128" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[SUB TOTAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="###0.00">
                <reportElement x="478" y="69" width="59" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL2}/100.00*12.36]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="478" y="49" width="59" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="none"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL}+$F{fseamount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="69" width="128" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Service Tax At 12.36%]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="###0.00">
                <reportElement x="464" y="252" width="73" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL2}+$V{Tax}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You should post your jrxml file

Comment: Are you using *iReport* or *JasperReports API*?

Comment: @AlexK yes i m using ireport..

Comment: @AlexK i have posted jrxml file

Comment: @AlexK I want print the total amount that is calculated inside the field provided in letterhead (that is field next to label Please pay this amount label) i have posted the letter head image.

Comment: I have put the total field in Summary Section of ireport

Comment: Do you have already variable for calculating this sum? If yes, what is the name?

Comment: TOTAL2 and TAX variable is together added to get the total

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16133/discussion-between-alex-k-and-azuu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to change ***Position Type*** to **Fix Relative to Bottom** or **Float** for this *textField* (with *`$V{TOTAL2}+$V{Tax}`* expression).

```xml
<textField pattern="###0.00">
    <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="464" y="252" width="73" height="20"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL2}+$V{Tax}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: I tried this but the issue when the number of lines in detail band changes it effects the position. Again the position is changed.